# Windows 8.1 - Won't boot (0xc000000f), bcdedit fails

Tags: windows, boot, diskpart, bcdedit

I’m pretty much stuck at this point. So, backstory:

Windows was installed on one of the SSDs currently in my tower. I bought a new SSD to install Windows (8.1 64 bit) on. Windows installation went fine, booted up, and formatted the old SSD from within Windows (this seems to have been a mistake, but I didn’t realize that at the time).

Despite formatting the old SSD, whenever I tried to boot I was told that there were 2 Windows installations. Apparently, when I formatted the old drive, not all of the partitions were removed.

So, I booted up with the repair utility, went into cmd, and deleted the non-primary partitions on the old SSD (there were 2 – think they were system and recovery, although I’m forgetting now).

Reboot – computer won’t boot. Getting the 0xc000000f “The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible” error.

Troubleshooting so far:

Automatic repair doesn’t fix anything (I’ve never had luck with it though)
If I go to install a new version of Windows, the drives and partitions are all there. The SSD is functioning, I at least know that.

I’ve essentially gone through this guide: https://neosmart.net/wiki/recovering-windows-bootloader/
Unfortunately, I’m not getting anywhere. I’m not even entirely sure how to describe the errors I’m getting, so I’ve just included pictures of every step (I can't actually post them though so I just included a photobucket link).

http://s319.photobucket.com/user/DGalt11/library/Computer%20Issue

Am I completely screwed here (i.e. reformat and reinstall?)?

Thanks

Comment: What does `DISKPART` -> `LIST VOL` display? That will show your volumes (with drive letters). I've got a feeling you're following the tutorials literally and not using YOUR drive letters for the current WinRE session. `C:\\`` within WinRE might not be your actual system `C:\\` - hence the "Path not found" and "File not found" errors...

Answer (score -1):

You deleted the boot partition (EFI System Partition or the active partition) on the old SSD.

You could restore all partitions you have deleted - google and find some tool (I would suggest "TestDisk" for partition recovery).

You only need either an "active partition" on old SSD if disk uses a MBR or an [EFI System Partition (ESP) + Microsoft Reserved Partition (MRP)] if the disk uses a GPT.

Then you can [repair the Windows BCD](http://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/RepairWindowsBCD.html).

---

If second SSD (where you installed Windows 8.1) has ESP and MRP partitions just put it as first disk in firmware and do a [Repair Windows BCD](http://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/RepairWindowsBCD.html).